# Why is DISPLAY=:0 incorrect when I only have 1 screen

Tags: x11, display

I've never connected my laptop to an external monitor so I am always using the laptop's primary display.  Occasionally, when waking from sleep, I realize that some of the GUI apps (e.g. `gitk`, `git gui`) stop working and give the error

```
application-specific initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

Every time, this is fixed by `export DISPLAY=:1`.  Why does this happen?  What is happening under the hood that requires me to manually change my `DISPLAY` variable?

Comment: Possibly your X server gets restarted when waking from sleep for whatever reason, and then uses the next display slot. Check system logs.

Comment: An X11 display is not the same as a monitor or screen. Yes it uses these words to mean different things. A Display is one or more screens, a keyboard and a pointing device. However what you described sounds vary odd indeed.

Comment: Probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/issues/332) though I am already using a newer tmux